# How to centre a div element?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to centre a div element with the following code, which works. But when I change the top/bottom margin to anything other than 0 (e.g. margin: 10 auto;), the div will be aligned to the left of the page, why is that?

```
#container {
    width: 960px;
    height: 960px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    font-size: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a working example of your code

Comment: you need to add uni ex: `10px auto`

Comment: try adding display:block to the #container and try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add margin value' unit  ex (px, rem, em)

```css
#container {
    width: 260px;
    height: 260px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    font-size:9px;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
</div>
```